# How to use Sensu email handler for contact routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, sensu

Suppose I am checking some metrics of AWS instances using sensu plugins and need to trigger email alerts only to a specific instance owner rather than a cloud operations team how can it be done.

As per my research each check has a contact list but how can we make this contact list specific to an instance. Any ideas would help.

Comment: if you want to check metrics of ec2 instance, why don't you go with AWS cloud watch and use SNS to send email to the specific instance owner.Just create an alarm and use SNS to send Email.

Comment: Its just that my client has recently started usuing Sensu for all AWS metrics monitoring and the main reason for them is that in sensu they have graphite and grafana interface for better monitoring

Comment: What do you mean by instance owner? Did you create a EC2 `tag` called `owner` ? or the user who launched the instance?

Comment: @helloV In my case its the application owner, which is not something I can get from the instance metadata, I have my own lookup for instance -> instance owner mapping